# $D$ and $H$ in macroscopic Maxwell's equation: auxiliary or constitutive?

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations

I'm not a physicist.  I want to understand the macroscopic [Maxwell's equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations). But after reading Wikipedia and other Googled stuffs, I got very confused. In particular, $D$ and $H$ have two different equations, respectively. One group is called auxiliary fields:

$$B = \mu_0(H+M),$$
$$D = \epsilon_0E+P.$$

The other group is called constitutive relations:

$$B = \mu H,$$
$$D = \epsilon E.$$

Which group of equations are relevant to the macroscopic Maxwell's equation if we consider the case with polarization ($P$ and $M$ present). My aim is to learn computational electromagnetic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both pairs of equations are equivalent. In the first equation have the magnetic flux density $B$, which results from the applied magnetic field $H$, and the magnetization $M$. You can think of the magnetization as the response of the material to the applied field. The magnetization is related to the field strength by

$$M = \chi_m H \,.$$

where $\chi_m$ is the [magnetic susceptibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_susceptibility). If $\chi_m > 0$, the material is paramagnetic, meaning the response has the same sign as the applied field (thus the total flux density grows). If it is $< 0$, it is diamagnetic, and the resulting flux density is smaller.

There is a different way of writing the same physics:

$$B =  \mu_0( H + M) = \mu_0( H + \chi_m H)  =  \mu_0 (\underbrace{1 + \chi_m}_{ =\; \mu_r}) H$$

$$ \Rightarrow \quad B = \mu_0\mu_r H = \mu H$$

So the same information given by the magnetic susceptibility $\chi_m$ is also in the relative permeability $\mu_r$.

The situation is very similar for the electric field. An applied electric field $E$ moves the electrons in the material, leading to polarization $P$. Together both form the displacement field $D$. There is a slight difference in notation here, though. In the case of the magnetic field, $\mu_0$ is multiplied by $(H+M)$. For the electric field, only $E$ is multiplied by $\varepsilon_0$, not $P$. So  the equation for $P$ needs a factor of $\varepsilon_0$:

$$P = \varepsilon_0 \chi_e E \quad \Rightarrow \quad 1 + \chi_e = \varepsilon_r$$

$$ \Rightarrow \quad D = \varepsilon_0\varepsilon_r E = \varepsilon E$$

Comment: In the first sentence, is "the magnetization H" ought to be "magnetization M"? Thanks for clear explanations.

Comment: @jdm They are not equivalent, the first pair are the definitions of the fields D and H. The second pair are the constitutive relations which hold only in the special case where the material is isotropic and linear; in this case E is proportional to P and B is proportional to M.